# Exclusive or between N bit sets

Tags: java, string, bit-manipulation, bitset

I am implementing a program in Java using BitSets and I am stuck in the following operation:

Given N BitSets return a BitSet with 0 if there is more than 1 one in all the BitSets, and 1 otherwise

As an example, suppose we have this 3 sets:

- 10010
- 01011
- 00111
- 11100 expected result

For the following sets :

- 10010
- 01011
- 00111
- 10100
- 00101
- 01000 expected result

I am trying to do this exclusive with bit wise operations, and I have realized that what I need is literally the exclusive or between all the sets, but not in an iterative fashion,
so I am quite stumped with what to do. Is this even possible?

I wanted to avoid the costly solution of having to check each bit in each set, and keep a counter for each position...

Thanks for any help

Edit : as some people asked, this is part of a project I'm working on. I am building a time table generator and basically one of the soft constraints is that no student should have only 1 class in 1 day, so those Sets represent the attending students in each hour, and I want to filter the ones who have only 1 class.

Comment: It isn't true that what you need is literally the exclusive or. If you have three sets all full of 1s then their exclusive or is all-1 but you're supposed to produce all-0. May I ask what you're actually aiming to achieve here? (It sounds like homework but I hope you'd have said so if you were asking for help with your homework.)

Comment: I believe that need one _iterative fashion_ =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want with two values. One has the bits set at least once, the second has those set more than once. The combination can be used to determine those set once and no more.

```
int[] ints = {0b10010, 0b01011, 0b00111, 0b10100, 0b00101};
int setOnce = 0, setMore = 0;
for (int i : ints) {
    setMore |= setOnce & i;
    setOnce |= i;
}
int result = setOnce & ~setMore;
System.out.println(String.format("%5s", Integer.toBinaryString(result)).replace(' ', '0'));
```

prints

```
01000
```

Comment: As I read the requirements, he wants `~setMore`, but good solution whichever reading is correct, +1.

Comment: That matches the text, but the examples suggest one and only one.

Comment: Ah, I didn't inspect the examples ;)

Comment: I didn't understand the text. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, you can't do this without checking every bit in each set. If you could solve this question without checking some arbitrary bit, then that would imply that there exist two solutions (i.e. two different ones for each of the two values that bit can be).

If you want a more efficient way of computing the XOR of multiple bit sets, I'd consider representing your sets as integers rather than with sets of individual bits. Then simply XOR the integers together to arrive at your answer. Otherwise, it seems to me that you would have to iterate through each bit, check its value, and compute the solution on your own (as you described in your question).