# What is the most elegant way to remove values that have duplicates from a Java array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops

I'm trying to take an array, check if there are any dupes, and remove the all instances of that letter, The method I'm currently trying to use is very ugly

Example;

```
In: ABBCCDE
Out: ADE
```

Or

```
In: BCACDF
Out: BADF
```

I'm currently using two `for` loops to find the dupes, adding the Char[] for that dupe to a OTHER array, then looping around with 2 more for loops deleting the chars from my ErrorArray.

Comment: "Most elegant" is to use a Java `Set`.

Comment: I've read about set, I know set would not let me have dupes, but I want to remove both versions of a dupe, EG ABB would become A, because both "B"s would be removed

Comment: Why would you want to remove *both* dupes?

Comment: Why is not important (there are multiple applications to that). My question is: is the array ALWAYS ordered like the examples you provided? because that changes the algorithm drastically

Comment: No, It can be any string, I will edit the question thanks

Comment: What about **"ABBBC"** will result in **"ABC"** or **"AC"**?

Comment: you want to keep the original ordering?

Comment: what about triplets ? aaabbccc would be ac right ?

Comment: "Elegant" is subjective but for values of capital letters (as in original post), this can be done with bitmasks and very efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SET` allows you to remove any duplicates value automatically. Since you are using array, you will need to convert it using `Arrays.asList(T.. a)`

```
SET<Character> uniqueCharacters = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(yourArray));
```

Answer (score 5):

This might be a solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] arr = { 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E' };
    Set<Character> in = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Character> dupe = new HashSet<>();
    for (char c : arr) {
        if (!dupe.contains(c)) {
            if (in.contains(c)) {
                dupe.add(c);
                in.remove(c);
            } else {
                in.add(c);
            }
        }
    }
    char[] arrR = new char[in.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (char c : in) {
        arrR[i++] = c;
    }
    for (char c : arrR) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I coded the same, esentially, I'll remove my answer. I just suggest you to change the first HashSet to a LinkedHashSet in case we want to keep the original ordering.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static String removeDuplicateChars (String sText)
{
    String sResult = "";
    char[] caText = sText.toCharArray();
    int[] iaAsciiIndex = new int[128];

    for (int i=0 ; i<caText.length; i++)
    {
        iaAsciiIndex[caText[i]] += 1;
    }

    for (int i=0 ; i<iaAsciiIndex.length ; i++)
    {
        if (iaAsciiIndex[i] == 1)
            sResult += (char)i;
    }

    return sResult;
}
```

Comment: Is this your proposed solution? Maybe you could explain what it's doing/why it's useful?

Comment: My powers of explanation are pretty bad, but here goes:

There are 128 characters in the ASCII table, hence an int array of 128 has been created. Each character in the string is looped through and the ASCII array is updated by an increment of 1, where the index matches the character's ASCII code. After, the ASCII array is then looped through, and where there has only been one occurence of a character, it is appended to a string.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many solutions to this problem, and depending on the input the best solution varies.

The solution proposed by romedius in his answer is good, just like the one proposed by Alex in his comment on Makoto's answer.

If you consider the HashSet/HashMap to have operations that are O(1), then they are O(n).
However, reality says this is rarely the case, and it depends on how appropiate your hash function and the resizing of the array of linked lists (or whatever structure is used internally - Java uses LL by default) are.

So, for example: Java's HashMaps and HashSets have a worst case insertion of O(n), since they validate for duplicates and thus iterate through the linked list, instead of just adding to its tail. This only happens when the number of collisions is high.

If you know the size of your input, it is a good idea to set the size of the HashSet/HashMap to it: HashMap(int initialCapacity) constructor does this. This way you prevent resizing problems of the structure, which can hit on performance heavily.

If you don't, it will use the default capacity. Then you only depend on how good the hash function is.

A reliable solution that is O(n log n) is to sort the input, then just iterate once checking if either the previous or following position of the array is equal to the one selected and if any are, then don't add it. This second part is O(n). The sort is guaranteed to be O(n logn) and if you're using Java 7 it will use timsort which is very fast.

If I was interviewing someone, I would accept either solution.

Comment: I don't think sets or sorting are necessary. Please see my answer.

Comment: That one is excellent! And yes, I just suggested one solution. I will analyze it later, but I guess a bitmask should facilitate an O(n) solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't define *elegant*, but I submit using bitmasks and XOR to remove dupes. I argue this is elegant and extremely efficient, as it obviates navigating sets for removal of dupes.

(This only works for upper-case letters, but is easy to extend.)

This is a class which is key to the idea. It is a simple wrapper around a BitSet, used to denote the current char, or which chars have been seen, etc:

```
class Bitmask {
    private static final int NUM_BITS = 26;
    private static final int OFFSET = 65;
    // e.g. {A,C,D} == [1,0,1,1,0, ...]
    BitSet bitset = new BitSet(NUM_BITS);

    public Bitmask() {}

    public Bitmask(Bitmask bitmask) {
        this.bitset = (BitSet) bitmask.bitset.clone();
    }
    public void set(char c) {
        int whichBit = (int) c - OFFSET;
        bitset.set(whichBit);        
    }

    public List<Character> getAllSet() {
        List<Character> all = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BITS; i++) {
            if (bitset.get(i)) {
                char c = (char) (OFFSET + i);
                all.add(new Character(c));
            }
        }        
        return all;
    }

    public void xor(Bitmask bitmask) {
        this.bitset.xor(bitmask.bitset);
    }

    public void or(Bitmask bitmask) {
        this.bitset.or(bitmask.bitset);
    }

    public void and(Bitmask bitmask) {
        this.bitset.and(bitmask.bitset);
    }

    public void andNot(Bitmask bitmask) {
        this.bitset.andNot(bitmask.bitset);
    }    
}
```

That looks verbose, but the payoff is in the algorithm, which owes a big debt to [this answer on XOR for N bitsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388074/exclusive-or-between-n-bit-sets).

```
char[] input = {'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};  //expect 'ACDE'
//char[] input = {'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'};
//char[] input = {'A', 'C', 'G' };

Bitmask moreThanOnceBitmask = new Bitmask();
Bitmask onceBitmask = new Bitmask();

for(char c : input) {
    Bitmask thisBitmask = new Bitmask();
    thisBitmask.set(c);
    Bitmask tmpOnceBitmask = new Bitmask(onceBitmask);
    // we've seen 'char c' at least once
    onceBitmask.or(thisBitmask);
    // we've seen 'char c' more than once
    tmpOnceBitmask.and(thisBitmask);
    moreThanOnceBitmask.or(tmpOnceBitmask);
}

// we want 'at least once' but not 'more than once'
Bitmask finalBitmask = new Bitmask(onceBitmask);
finalBitmask.andNot(moreThanOnceBitmask);

// build list

System.out.println(finalBitmask.getAllSet().toString());
```

Comment: you do realize your solution breaks down when there are an odd # of a given letter right?  If you don't believe me add a third occurance of the character 'B'

Comment: Yep, my first post was too simple, and failed on the case you mention. But the updated answer (with the Bitmask class) is correct (I think). Please refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Reasonable solution with Guava's multiset classes:

```
    char[] chars = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'E' };

    Multiset<Character> set =  LinkedHashMultiset.create(Chars.asList(chars));

    for (char c : chars ) {
       int cnt = set.count(c);
       if (cnt > 1) {
           set.remove(c, cnt);
       }
    }

    char[] singles = Chars.toArray(set);

    System.out.println(new String(singles));
```

PS:  It's important to use the LinkedHashMultiset rather than HashMultiset, since the LinkedHashMultiset version retains the insertion order when you iterate through it, the HashMultiset does not.

And i don't claim this is the most memory efficient solution as there's a lot of temporary collections getting created.

However, from a code standpoint it's simple, and someone can deduce what you are trying to do by just looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

- Solutions based on `Set` are not elegant due to the lack of support
  in Java for conversions from `char[]` to `Set<Character>` and back.
- The loops required for the above conversions are more efficiently used
  in performing the actual processing required by the problem.
- I submit that the extreme simplicity of the following solution makes it elegant.
- It is also efficient, though at the expense of a (somewhat) large array which size could possibly be
  reduced based on knowledge of the required input character set.

  ```
  public class Test extends TestCase {

      public void testDupes() {
          assertEquals("ADE", noDupes("ABBCCDE".toCharArray()));
          assertEquals("BADF", noDupes("BCACDF".toCharArray()));
      }

      public String noDupes(char[] in) {
          int[] count = new int[Character.MAX_VALUE];
          for (char c: in)
              count[c]++;
          StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
          for (char c: in)
              if (count[c]==1)
                  out.append(c);
          return out.toString();
      }
  }
  ```